# Select parts of JSON and check if value is empty

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, curl

I have a question about selecting parts of a JSON object and check if they have a value or not.
I load the JSON from an API in PHP:

```
$json_url  ='http://api.url.com/api/gateway/call/1.4/getApp?appid=2631';
$ch = curl_init($json_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$str = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($str);
```

output of data is:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'app' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[2]
              public 'id' => string '2631' (length=4)
              public 'apptypeid' => string '3' (length=1)
              public 'organizerid' => string '913' (length=3)
              public 'accountId' => string '687' (length=3)
              public 'name' => string 'Meet in Liege' (length=13)
              public 'info' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'submit_description' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'category' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'app_icon' => string 'upload/appimages/2631/icon1024.png' (length=34)
              public 'homescreen' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'token' => string 'e6615c94a8b0fed28cdbec611669b19b' (length=32)
              public 'certificate' => string 'app2631' (length=7)
              public 'subdomain' => string 'mil13' (length=5)
              public 'cname' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'advancedFilter' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'status' => string 'inactive' (length=8)
              public 'isdeleted' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'creation' => string '2013-03-19 14:20:44' (length=19)
              public 'defaultlanguage' => string 'fr' (length=2)
              public 'visibleintapcrowd' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'applestoreid' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'address' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'lat' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'lon' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'telephone' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'email' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'website' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'contentmodule_css_phone' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'contentmodule_css_tablet' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'searchterms' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'fbid' => string '563672167017349' (length=15)
              public 'dropdb' => string '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (length=19)
              public 'bundle' => string 'com.tapcrowd.meetinliege2631' (length=28)
              public 'blankurl' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'header_html_phones' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'header_html_tablets' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'footer_html_phones' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'footer_html_tablets' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'themeid' => string '41' (length=2)
              public 'timestamp' => string '1368548676' (length=10)
              public 'subflavorid' => string '12' (length=2)
              public 'subflavortype' => string '3' (length=1)
              public 'subflavorpaidtype' => string '9999' (length=4)
              public 'show_external_ids_in_cms' => string '0' (length=1)
              public 'launcherview' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'responsive' => string '1' (length=1)
              public 'apptype' => string 'Event Flavor' (length=12)
              public 'channel' => string '1' (length=1)
              public 'aboutbuttonkey' => string 'About TapCrowd' (length=14)
              public 'aboutbuttonurl' => string 'http://m.tap.cr/about' (length=21)
      public 'appversion' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'events' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[3]
              public 'id' => string '5004' (length=4)
              .......
```

Now I would like to check if for example 'info', 'app_icon', 'address' and 'email' of app array are empty or not. 
Does anyone know how I can do this? And is this possible with JSON queries? And I would like to do my operations in javascript!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
if(empty($data->app[0]->info)){
    // info empty
}
if(empty($data->app[0]->app_icon)){
    // app_icon empty
}
if(empty($data->app[0]->address)){
    // address empty
}
if(empty($data->app[0]->email)){
    // email empty
}
```

If you're passing the json to javascript then use (assuming the json is assigned to a variable called `data`):

```
if(data.app[0].info.length === 0){
    // info empty
}
```

Then repeat for the others by replacing `info` with the name you want to check.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this in js?

Comment: Pass the json to javascript with the correct headers etc. and then use:    `if(data.app[0].info.length === 0){ /* empty */ }`

Answer (score 1):

json_decode returns a regular PHP object, so it should be easy. If I'm not mistaken, given your `$data` object's structure this would do it:

```
// Retrieve the app object from $data
$app = $data->app[0];

// Check whatever you want with the object elements
if empty($app->info) "info empty\n";
if empty($app->app_icon) "app_icon empty\n";
if empty($app->address) "address empty\n";
if empty($app->email) "email empty\n";
```

In case there are more `app` object entries in the array you might consider using `foreach` to process them all.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do:

```
if(trim($data->app[0]->info)=='' || is_null($data->app[0]->info)){
  echo "info empty";
}

if(trim($data->app[0]->app_icon)=='' || is_null($data->app[0]->app_icon)){
  echo "app_icon empty";
}

if(trim($data->app[0]->address)=='' || is_null($data->app[0]->address)){
  echo "address empty";
}

if(trim($data->app[0]->email)=='' || is_null($data->app[0]->email)){
  echo "email empty";
}
```

Comment: This won't work as `$data` is an object and you're using it as an array.